# How do I point my domain to my website that's hosted on an AWS EC2?

Tags: wordpress, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The registrar for my domain is godaddy, I go to their DNS records section and I changed the A name to the elastic IP associated with my instance. Now when I type my domain in the browser, my website appears! However, it forwards it to the IP of my server.

Things I've tried (whether logical or not):

1. I'm using wordpress multsite so I changed the  DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE in wp-config.php to my new domain. No luck. Reverted.
2. I changed the 'site_url' and 'home' in my database to point to my domain. No luck. Tried one at a time etc. Reverted.
3. Changed ServerName to my new domain in httpd.conf (apache).
4. sudo hostname www.... (don't know what that does)

So I'd like to simply have my website open without it showing the IP in the address bar. Can someone help?

Thanks

EDIT: 
[Here's the DNS page of godaddy](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s101/sh/62cd3f48-917e-405b-93c4-66f73214e24e/7267322444b1c658da7895bbe5c7d587), I've blanked out the ip in the A records, but it's just the ip of my server.

Comment: do you have a .htaccess file or a plugin perhaps doing some sort of redirection ?

Comment: @codenathan I just finished reading the first few chapters of the oreilly book DNS & BIND. I have a much better idea about what's happening now. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll rebuild and keep a closer eye on the .htaccess and plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set [Custom NS](https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-godaddy-12317) in godaddy with AWS dedicated IPs then set them as DNS. If you are using Linux instance with cPanel then just add the domain in cpanel's addon-domain.

If you are using Windows instance then you should configure IIS.

Comment: Thank you @Shahbaz it's not very intuitive. I took the public DNS of my EC2 and put it in the _domainconnect CNAME section. It still reverts back to the IP when I type it in the address bar. Does something else need to change or does it take a while to process?